# Change Element from List to end

Tags: c, pointers, nullpointerexception

I have a list in C and I want to sort it. All works fine, but when I want to change an Element with the last one in the list. The Element which I want to set to the end disapears.
Has somebody of you an idea whats the problem?

```
struPerson* sortListWithSelectSort(struPerson* pStart) {

    struPerson* pLastElement = NULL;
    struPerson* pLastElementToCompare = NULL;

    for (struPerson* pElement = pStart; pElement->pNext != NULL; pElement = pElement->pNext) {

        pLastElementToCompare = pElement;
        struPerson* pElementToCompare = pElement->pNext;

        do {

            //boolean 0 = false, 1 true
            short isGreater = 0;

            //compare if change must be
            if (strcmp(pElement->nachname, pElementToCompare->nachname) > 0) {
                isGreater = 1;
            }
            else if (strcmp(pElement->nachname, pElementToCompare->nachname) == 0) {
                if (strcmp(pElement->vorname, pElementToCompare->vorname) > 0) {
                    isGreater = 1;
                }
            }

            //change elements
            struPerson* pTemp = pElement;

            if (isGreater > 0) {
                struPerson* pTempElementToCompareNext = pElementToCompare->pNext;

                //change position
                //check if the element is pStart
                if (pStart == pElement) {
                    pStart = pElementToCompare;
                }
                else {
                    pLastElement->pNext = pElementToCompare;
                }

                //check if they are behind
                if (pTemp->pNext = pElementToCompare) {
                    pTempElementToCompareNext = pElementToCompare->pNext;
                    pElementToCompare->pNext = pElement;
                    pElement->pNext = pTempElementToCompareNext;
                    pElement = pElementToCompare;
                    pElementToCompare = pTemp;
                    pLastElementToCompare = pElement;
                }
                else {
                    pTempElementToCompareNext = pElementToCompare->pNext;
                    pElementToCompare->pNext = pTemp->pNext;
                    pElement->pNext = pTempElementToCompareNext;
                    pElementToCompare->pNext->pNext = pElement;
                    pElement = pElementToCompare;
                    pElementToCompare = pTemp;
                }
            }
            else {
                //set Pointer for next comparison
                pLastElement = pElement;
                pLastElementToCompare = pLastElementToCompare;
            }

            if (pElementToCompare->pNext == NULL) {
            }
            else {
                pElementToCompare = pElementToCompare->pNext;
            }

        } while (pElementToCompare->pNext != NULL);
    }
    return pStart;
}
```

Comment: Show the minimal amount of code that compiles and can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: (Without seeing code, I would venture a guess that if you have a pointer to the first and/or last element in the list, that is not itself part of the list, you are forgetting to update it when you update the first and/or last element. Or you are forgetting to update the pointer in the element right before the new last element.)

Comment: sorry when code is not the best i'm young and new here.

Comment: Wecome to Stack Overflow, then! Please read the [tour] and browse the [Help] to get an insight of how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: My idea is that you use: a) pencil, paper and eraser to draw the list and pointers and how they change and b) the debugger to step through the code to see what happens (while using the paper to track what points to where).

Comment: @LAG you just have = rather than a ==, see my answer

Comment: When you're having trouble spotting a coding error, that's an indication that your code may be too complex or insufficiently documented.  Some people like to recommend [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and that's fine as far as it goes, but you get more bang for the buck by making code comments out of your duck explanations.  That helps you avoid rethinking everything every time, and it may also help you notice inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

just under `//check if they are behind` : `if (pTemp->pNext = pElementToCompare) {` must be `if (pTemp->pNext == pElementToCompare) {`

I encourage you to compile requiring all the warnings, for instance `gcc -Wall ...` that helps to see that kind of error and more

in the block commented by `//set Pointer for next comparison` the assignement `pLastElementToCompare = pLastElementToCompare;` does nothing, must be an other one ?

Comment: Oh, thanks i'm such an idoit. But It still doesn't have an idea while it isn't working.

Comment: @LAG I did some tests and all seems ok (at least with the ==). Please give a non working example

Comment: I have a list sorted by that: A,L;Z,D;C,N;F,Z; (first one is "nachname" and second "vorname"). The result is: A,L;C,N;F,Z;Z,D;

Comment: with `Z,D;C,N;F,Z` I have a crash

Comment: I suppose you want to do a bubble sort no ?

Comment: My friend does a buble sort, I have to do another. Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: with a list it is not possible to directly access to the nth element, the bubble sort is the natural sort. Of course you can transform the list into a vector, sort the vector in O(nlog(n)) then modify the list to follow the sorted vector order. You can also make a vector pointing to the list cells then sort the vector modifying the cells attributes names. But I am not sure this is allowed for you :-))

Comment: @LAG I just see that in your code : `pLastElementToCompare = pLastElementToCompare;` (I edited my answer)

Comment: @JohnBollinger ah yes, the goal is probably to not go up to the end of the list each time because the last element(s) are already sorted, but that way do not works

Comment: To not use a bubble sort the more I think about to use a temporary vector the more I Like :) And you @LAG ?

Comment: @LAG, I've been trying to figure out what flavor of sort yours is supposed to be.  That you don't know yourself is ... illuminating.  You are unlikely to discover a brand new sorting algorithm of your own, so choose an existing one and implement it.  Insertion sort needs to work a bit differrently than usual when applied to singly-linked lists, which may be more than you're up for.  Perhaps a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) would be suitable?

Answer (score 0):

A working proposal, sorry I am too lazy to search more what is wrong in your version

```
#if 0
void exchange(struPerson* p1, struPerson* p2)
{
  char * s;

  s = p1->nachname;
  p1->nachname = p2->nachname;
  p2->nachname = s;

  s = p1->vorname;
  p1->vorname = p2->vorname;
  p2->vorname = s;

  /* exchange other fields except pNext of course
     this is the disadvantage of that solution */
}
#else
/* other way but you have to check this works with your definition of struPerson */
void exchange(struPerson* p1, struPerson* p2)
{
  struPerson p = *p1;
  struPerson * p1next = p1->pNext;
  struPerson * p2next = p2->pNext;

  *p1 = *p2;
  *p2 = p;
  p1->pNext = p1next;
  p2->pNext = p2next;
}
#endif

void sortListWithBubbleSort(struPerson* pStart) {
    int modified;

    do {
        modified = 0;

        struPerson* pElement;

        for (pElement = pStart; pElement->pNext != NULL; pElement = pElement->pNext) {
          int cmp = strcmp(pElement->nachname, pElement->pNext->nachname);

          if ((cmp > 0) ||
              ((cmp == 0) && (strcmp(pElement->vorname, pElement->pNext->vorname) > 0))) {
            exchange(pElement, pElement->pNext);
            modified = 1;
          }
        }
    } while (modified != 0);
}
```

As usual with the bubble sort it is not the right way to always check up to the last element because the last element(s) is/are already sorted after at least one turn, I let you improve that as an exercise :-)